# To get application id in particular file after spark-submit in cluster deploy mode

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark, log4j, cluster-analysis

I want to get application id in text file at local when I deploy application in cluster mode.

For this I had edited log4j.properties file and configs it for client but I is not working .

I had also followed this blog :*https://largecats.github.io/blog/2020/09/21/spark-cluster-mode-collect-log/* but do not get satisfactory  result.

I had also follow this *[spark-submit in cluster deploy mode get application id to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159364/spark-submit-in-cluster-deploy-mode-get-application-id-to-console)* but it is showing application id on console.

so, please anyone help me , I am stuck there of a week but do not get proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `tag` to your Spark app during submitting and later `ask Yarn` based on tag value.

`--conf spark.yarn.tags=tag-name`